# Proper way of declaring subclass constructer with both initialization lists and superclass constructor

Tags: c++, inheritance, initialization-list

My current situation is as follows. It is a more or less simple case of inheritance and I have multiple questions about it.

I have an abstract class (= it has pure virtual functions) with two variables `foo_` and `bar_`. `foo_` is set by a parameter in the constructor. `bar_` should default to 1000 for most subclasses, but I want one specific class to override it to 50000.

Here is a code snippet:

```
class Base {
 protected:
  const int foo_;
  const int bar_;
 public:
  Base(int foo) : foo_{foo}, bar_{1000} {}
}

class Derived : public Base {}
```

First, one quick question: Is it better practice to initialize `bar_` in the initialization list as I did in the example or do it at the top where the variable was declared as `const int bar_{1000};`?

Second quick question: Is it ok to use `{}` in initialization lists or should one use `()`?

How do I correctly write the constructor for the Derived class? I want to specifically call the constructor I defined for Base and also use an initalization list to set `bar_` to 50000.

My idea was something like this:

```
Derived(int foo) : Base(foo), bar_{50000} {}
```

**EDIT:** After a bit of trying I noticed that modifying bar_ in Derived's constructor list is apparently not possible, because `"bar_" is not a nonstatic data member or base class of class "Derived"`.

Comment: If you're just unsure about the syntax, compilers are very good about detecting problems with that. So why not try it and see if the compiler allows it?

Comment: best practice is to provide a [mcve] ;). What happened when you tried it? And better only one question per question

Comment: So, I tried it and apparently I'm not allowed to change `bar_` in the initialization list of Derived's constructor: "bar_" is not a nonstatic data member or base class of class "Derived". Obviously I won't be able to change it inside the constructor body, because it is constant.

Comment: The `Derived` constructor can't modify `bar_` anyway, because it is declared as `const`, so it can't be changed once it has been initialized by the `Base` constructor.  Which means `Derived` will have to pass an initial value to the `Base` constructor to initialize `bar_` with. Otherwise, don't declare `bar_` as `const`, then the `Derived` constructor *body* can modify `bar_` directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many aspects in this question to be tackled.

My preference for initialization goes to:

```
class Base {
 protected:
  const int foo_{};
  const int bar_{1000};
 public:
  Base(int foo) : foo_{foo} {}
}
```

The reasons I prefer this is because a class can have multiple constructors. This makes it easier to maintain the defaults.

For the question about the initialization, I give up. Just use the styleguide that is out there. (Currently they seem to be standardized on using {} everywhere) Outside of constructors, it's even a bigger mess to initialize, if you want to be horrified by the details, I can recommend: [Nicolai Josuttis "The Nightmare of Initialization in C++"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7DTlWPgX6zs).

For writing the constructor in the derived class, I'd argue your member shouldn't be protected. If it would be private, the only way to write it is:

```
class Base {
 private:
  const int foo_{};
  const int bar_{1'000};
 protected:
  Base(int foo, int bar) : foo_{foo}, bar_{bar} {}
 public:
  Base(int foo) : foo_{foo} {}
}

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    Derived(int foo) : Base{foo, 50'000} {}
}
```

With this, I would expose the access to them via a protected method. Even ignoring that advice, I would use this technique to intialize it as it's the easiest to understand what could happen if you only look at the 'Base' class.

Comment: you already had my +1 at "I give up", then private rather than protected would be worth another +1 ;)

Comment: I'd definitely give this video a watch tonight. You tend to learn alot of big and small things from listening to people who know their stuff. Right now I initialize as much as I can with {}, but who knows what else lurks out there.

Comment: @Hex the real annoyance of always using one style is figuring out which constructr is going to be selected. Example: you have a container, say `vector<int> demo{4};` that you want to contain 4 [value-initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) elements. Well, the braces smurfed you over in this case because [`demo` contains one element holding the value 4](https://ideone.com/KSLK5X) because you got the initializer list constructor instead of element count constructor.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it better practice to initialize bar_ in the initialization list as I did in the example or do it at the top where the variable was declared as const int bar_{1000};?

This is not so much about "best pratice" but more about "what do you want"? `1000` is the default inital value that gets "overriden" by a initializer in a constructor. You can have default initializer and eg one constructor that uses a different initializer and one that doesn't.

> How do I correctly write the constructor for the Derived class?

You can write a protected constructor that allows you to pass both values:

```
class Base {
 protected:
  const int foo_;
  const int bar_;
  Base(int foo, int bar) : foo_(foo), bar_(bar) {}
 public:
  Base(int foo) : foo_{foo}, bar_{1000} {}
};

class Derived : public Base {
    public:
    Derived(int foo) : Base(foo,5000) {}
};
```

Comment: Why am I not able to "accept" multiple answers :( ? Both you and @JVApen added valuable information to this. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Hex thats how it works. Doesnt matter who came first. fwiw I don't mind, the other answer is definitely more complete and mine doesn't  add anything so its the other answer that I would accept also